# Apache2 Cannot make work simple mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I would like to configure my apache2.4.7 to redirect requests internally like this:

```
/app/download/somefile => /app/download.php/somefile
```

or sth comparable. After various attempts which all don't work I've come down to a very simple replacement which also simply refuses to work. I have added 2 lines to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^/app/testtest\.php" "/app/index.php"
```

Didn't work. Then I've added the same thing inside a directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app>
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule "^/app/testtest\.php" "/app/index.php"
</Directory>
```

Same thing, just no effect. I had also tried this rule inside an .htaccess file, also no effect.
/app/index.php exists, I'm sure I'm editing the right config (added syntax errors, then server doesn't come up when restarting) and I'm running out of ideas.
I did *not* forget to enable the rewrite module, I executed

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Any help is appreciated.

========================== UPDATE ============================

Ok, I made the rewrite part work by adding the following to sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
RewriteEngine On                    
RewriteRule "^/app/(.+)" "/app/$1.php"
```

Don't know why it doesn't work in any other location but, fine, better than nothing.
Now, I can access /app/index but not /app/index.php which would rewrite to /app/index.php.php which doesn't exist. So I added a condition

```
RewriteEngine On                                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule "^/app/(.+)" "/app/$1.php"
```

I read in several forums and documentation that this is the way to do it. But again, **does not work at all**. It doesn't work neither for php files (still can't access them with extention .php) nor for image files. Here is an extract from the logs:

```
 script '/var/www/html/app/icons/bin_closed.png.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Why are my conditions being ignored? thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. In this very case the RewriteCond needs the full path of the file. Everything works smoothly when I configure it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On                                     
RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule "^/app/(.+)" "/app/$1.php"
```

I had copied the stuff from examples which somehow don't work exactly the same way as my scenario...